# Assuming that $a$ and $b$ commute, prove the following: $ab = ba$ if and only if $aba^{−1} = b$

Tags: abstract-algebra

$ab = ba$ can be written as: $aba^{−1} = b$

$aba^{−1}$ is a conjugate of $b$ and has order $q$. Thus $aba^{−1}$ is a power of $b$.

$aba^{−1} = b^k$ for some integer $k$.

By induction, $a^{m}(ba)^{−m} = b^{{k}^{m}}$ for all $m \geq 1$.

Taking $m = p$ gives $b = b^{k^p}$. $b$ has order $q$, this implies $kp \equiv 1 \mod q$, so $k \mod q$ has order $1$ or $p$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/(q))^\times$, a group of order $q − 1$. If the order is $p$, then $p | (q − 1)$, so $q \equiv 1 \mod p$. But $q\cdot 6\equiv 1 \mod p$ by hypothesis (aha).
Thus the order of $k$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/(q))^\times$ is $1$, so $k \equiv 1 \mod q$ and $aba^{−1} = b$

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) formatting.

Comment: Your title says," Assuming $a$ and $b$ commute, prove that $a$ and $b$ commute if and only if $aba^{-1}=b$." That's weird. I think you just want to say "Show that $a,b$ commute if and only if $aba^{-1}=b.$

Comment: What are you trying to prove exactly? Why do you need to introduce the order of the elements? Why would they be of finite order?

Comment: Also, as a general rule, don't put long questions in the title. Shorten it and put the long version of the question in the body.

Answer (score 4):

$$aba^{-1}=b\Leftrightarrow aba^{-1}a=ba\Leftrightarrow ab=ba.$$